# How to assign a @Projection to a @GetMapping spring servlet endpoint?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-data, spring-rest

I have an `@Entity Person` class, and want to expose that via a webservice. There should be a method just exposing all details, and and endpoint only exposing a *view* excerpt.

Can I use Spring `@Projection` for that purpose without having to manually extract the fields I want to expose? I'd prefer just returning a `List<Person>` but render only certain details for certain endpoints.

```
@RestController
public class BookingInfoServlet {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository dao;

    @GetMapping("/persons")
    public List<Person> persons() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }

    //TODO how can I assign the Projection here?
    @GetMapping("/personsView")
    public List<Person> persons() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }

    //only expose certain properties
    @Projection(types = Person.class)
    public interface PersonView {
        String getLastname();
    }
}

@Entity
public class Person {
    @id
    long id;

    String firstname, lastname, age, etc;
}

interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `@Projection` only works with spring data rest. I believe you could try this:

```
@Projection(name = "personView",  types = Person.class)
public interface PersonView {
    String getLastname();
}
```

And on your repo, you need something like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = PersonView.class)
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

Comment: But that would force my normal `@GetMapping("/persons")` endpoint to also return the view only. I want to decide by endpoint explicit which view to use.

Comment: hmm ... understood. @Projection may not solve this I think. Maybe use @JsonFilter? I need to research exactly how to do it. I will message back if no one else tries it soon enough. Or better still, GraphQL if at all possible.

Comment: The annotation has `path` attribute. Use it to provide the path of the url

Comment: `@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = PersonView.class, path = "person")`